# Create all subvectors of a certain length (moving window)

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

What is the best way to retrieve all subvectors of a given length? For example, all subvectors with the length 3 would be:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
k <- 3
embed(vec, k)[, k:1]
```